# How can a STACK be FIFO?

Tags: stack, fifo, x86-16

Got astonished when I read on the page 4 of [this](https://viewer.zoho.com/docs/kuGdt) article that stack in 8086 uses FIFO!!!
How can a STACK be FIFO?

Is the article wrong or there is a concept behind it??? I searched for about an hour but some websites said that it is FIFO and some LIFO How can it be both!
Expecting the correct answer here...
Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack pointed to by the SP register on '86 and later Intel is a push-down stack - last in, first out. 'FIFO' is a mistype, I expect.